# Safari "position: fixed" is overlapped on scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

On Safari (Mac)** when I scroll on [Bhooks.com](https://bhooks.com), the cards overlap the footer and the header of the webpage (with position: fixed). So far I'm unable to figure out why and I'm hoping to find some help here.

I also upgraded Bootstrap to the latest version, just to make sure.

Here's a screenshot of the issue:
[image]

I know it's a very specific bug and I don't have a small minimal example (because developing on my Mac VM is a nightmare). But at least the problem is easily accessible and easy to debug.

Thanks for your help!

** in my case macOS mojave 10.14.3 with Safari 12.0.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely a **z-index** order problem in the Safari. Try this CSS:

```
.bhooksBookCard {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Find this solution in [this thread](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/safari-for-ios-z-index-ordering-bug-while-scrolling-a-page-with-a-fixed-element/)

Please try and let me know if it fixed your problem. Tested in the inspector and seems like it works.

Comment: Oooh I had tried that only for individual **.card**s but never bothered to try the z-index:1 value in the class itself. It indeed doesn't work for (any) first row, but for the successive ones. How strange, but it's a big step forward.

Comment: Changing the **.hardcover_front**'s z-index didn't help, neither did increasing the header's or footer's. I also tried to add an empty div with **z-index: 1** at the front of the first cards, but also unsuccessfully.
This is probably a Safari bug I should report, or what do you think?

Comment: I'll expert more with your page and I let you know.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for your help, it works! Much appreciated, I wouldn't have figured it out without you!

Comment: Great! I'm was glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/jun/05/ipad-scroll-issues-with-fixed-content

check this out,

removing overflow: auto, and –webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch from the container that parallels to the overlapping tag will help you

but, some scrolling issue may persist